# Unable to fire mysql query without using volley

Tags: android

**Error:** `java.sql.SQLException: Column count doesn't match value count at row 1`

**Problem:** Im inserting data in `tbl_emp_salary` table & all column of this table is int type. When I execute the query then I get the error as below:

`java.sql.SQLException: Column count doesn't match value count at row 1`,

```
enter code here submit.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v)
        {
            if (Data.emp_email!=null)
            {
               

                query_sd="insert into tbl_emp_salary(EMP_ID,EMP_BASIC_SALARY,EMP_D_AL,EMP_H_RENT_AL,EMP_TRAVEL_AL,EMP_MED_AL,EMP_PF_DEDU" +
                        "EMP_INCOME_TAX,EMP_TDS)values('"+FragmentPersonalDetails.srno+"','"+Data.basic_salary+"','"+Data.dearnessallowance+"'," +
                        "'"+Data.houserenetallowance+"','"+Data.travelallowance+"','"+Data.medicalallowance+"','"+Data.pf+"'," +
                        "'"+Data.incometax+"','"+Data.tds+"')";
                try
                {
                    ps=con.prepareStatement(query_sd);
                    n1=ps.executeUpdate();
                    if (n1>0)
                    {
                        Toast.makeText(getContext(), "Record inserted", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                    }
                    else
                    {
                        Toast.makeText(getContext(), "n1 fail...", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                    }
                }
                catch (SQLException e) {
                    e.printStackTrace();

                }
            }
            else
            {
                Toast.makeText(getContext(), "emp_email is null", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
            }


        }
    });
```

I have also tried "++" in spite of '"++"' in the query syntax but I m fail. when I click submit button then error generated which I mention above.

How to solve?

Comment: Do you have column `EMP_PF_DEDUEMP_INCOME_TAX` ? no? then please, debug your code and check `query_sd` in debugger ... off-topic: 1. do you know Bobby Tables? [You should know him ...](https://xkcd.com/327/) 2. Using jdbc directly on android platform is not a good idea

Comment: Sir,  EMP_PF_DEDU" +
                        "EMP_INCOME_TAX <<== this has break because I have press the enter key in my android code. My query is correct sir

Comment: No, it is not correct ... please provide full error with stack ... there should be full SQL (which is not correct)...

Comment: The insert statement is wrong! End of story. Debug the code and fix a typo/missing char

Comment: but when I put the int value in spite of int variable then it is execute successfully.

Answer (score 0):

**I have missed the comma (,) between `enter code here`EMP_PF_DEDU" +
"EMP_INCOME_TAX** now the correct code is `enter code here`EMP_PF_DEDU," +
"EMP_INCOME_TAX